# Inject bean in GatewayFilter of Spring Cloud

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I am creating a custom bean in spring cloud GatewayFilter. but I am unable to inject any bean using @Autowired. I get null. whereas when I create a GlobalFilter I am able to inject beans.

How should i instantiate any bean in a GatewayFilter.

```
@Component
public class FileFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<FileFilter.Config> {

    public FileFilter() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return new FileRouteBasedFilter();
    }

    public static class Config {

    }

}
```

```
public class FileTransferRouteBasedFilter implements GatewayFilter, Ordered {

@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate  // is always null

  @Value("${custom.url}")
    private String url;   // also always null

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        return exchange.getSession().doOnNext(webSession -> printSession(webSession)).then(chain.filter(exchange));
    }

    private WebSession printSession(WebSession webSession) {

        log.info("SessionId sent to File Transfer  " + webSession.getId());

        return webSession;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 1;
    }

}
```